# What exactly is the "diagonal embedding" in the supersymmetric topological twist?

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory, yang-mills

Consider $\mathcal{N}=2$ pure SYM theory. If we want to put the theory in a 4-manifold we take its topological twist. The global symmetry group
$$G= SU(2)_{+} \times SU(2)_{-} \times SU(2)_I \times U(1)_R $$ goes to
$$ G'=SU(2)_{+} \times SU(2)'_{-} \times U(1)_R $$
where $SU(2)'_{-} = \text{diag}( SU(2)_{-} \times SU(2)_I)$

This $SU(2)'_{-}$ goes by the name **diagonal embedding** of $ SU(2)_{-} \times SU(2)_I$.

1. **What does this actually mean though?**
2. And how can I see how the original busy fields, say the gauge boson $A_{\mu}$ change representation after the twist?

Comment: The diagonal embedding for *any* mathematical object $X$ is commonly understood to be the map $X\to X\times X,x\mapsto(x,x)$.

Comment: But what if you have $X \times Y$ as in the case of twisting?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. You're embedding $\mathrm{SU}(2)\to\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$ here, no? The subscripts are just decorations to keep track of which group does what physically, but they're all the same group.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example? The diagonal embedding only keeps elements of which parts of $SU(2)_{-} \times SU(2)_R$?

Comment: @Marion, Do you find the explicit construction of the diagonal embedding? I am thankful to you if you write the answer.